# Appendix section in beamer with handout mode

Tags: beamer

I want to make a presentation and add some slides at the end as an appendix. The normal slides should have transitions "<+->", but the appendix ones should be like handout. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

[image: Beamer presentation with appendix]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}                % uncomment to uncover everything step-wise

\begin{frame}{A Frame}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item One
      \item Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<1->}                % uncomment to uncover everything step-wise
\appendix
\begin{frame}{\appendixname}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item Additional One
      \item Additional Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can determine the frame transitions on a frame-per-frame basis

cfr's solution is clearly better if you have quite a few frames in a row with the same transition type. I typically use some of my frames with transitions and others to write on with a stylus so I don't want transitions on these frames because I'd lose everything I write at every transition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[<+->]{A Frame}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item One
      \item Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\appendix
\begin{frame}[<1->]{\appendixname}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item Additional One
      \item Additional Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note you can omit the `[<1->]` on the second frame because this is the default behavior unless you use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}`